# I would like to make multiples simultaneous outgoing call using twilio

Tags: android, parsing, twilio, twilio-twiml

Scenario: at 2PM, I have a message (ex: your money has been transfered) I want to deliver to 20 phone numbers via an outgoing call not SMS.

the Calls should happen at exactly 2PM with a 1 or 2 minutes of error margin.

What it is the best aproach to implement this scenario?

do I need 20 Twilio phone numbers or less/one to make simultaneous call? if yes, is there a best practice on how to manage a pool of available Phone numbers.

NS: I am new to Twilio

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Twilio evangelist here.

All you'll need is one phone number and the REST API to tell Twilio each phone call that you want us to make.  You can call the REST API as fast as you want and Twilio will queue each outbound call request, initiating them at rate of one call per second.

Hope that helps.